# При запуске приложения появляются ошибки, указывающие на файл webpack.config.js. Как правильно настроить конфигурацию?

Tags: angular

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно настроить webpack.config.js. При запуске приложения - такие ошибки :
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'awesome-typescript-loader, html-loader' in 'K:\SportsStore_3'

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'awesome-typescript-loader, html-loader' in 'K:\SportsStore_3'

ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?https://localhost (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'awesome-typescript-loader, html-loader' in 'K:\SportsStore_3'
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?https://localhost (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.ts app[2]

ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?https://localhost (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/polyfills.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'awesome-typescript-loader, html-loader' in 'K:\SportsStore_3'
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?https://localhost (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/polyfills.ts polyfills[2]

```
** Часть файла webpack.config.js: **
`    
, module: {
    rules: [   //загрузчик для ts
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,                                 
            use: [
                 {                        
                  loader: `'awesome- 
                  typescript-loader, 
                  html-loader'`,
               options: { 
                configFileName:                     
                path.resolve(__dirname, 
                `'tsconfig.json'`)}
                },
                `'angular2-template- 
                 loader'`
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: `'html-loader'`
        }
    ]
},
` 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка может происходить из-за того, что не установлены awesome-typescript-loader, html-loader:

`npm i -D awesome-typescript-loader html-loader`